# Checkbox update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I would like to know how to update a checkbox using an update statement in the code behind.

I am using a gridview with order information with a checkbox to set if the order is completed or not. Initially it is set to false.

I have a dropdownlist with the order id number that I am using in my update statement (the variable I use is OrderID)

I tried this update statement but it seems like it is not working:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Order SET OrderCompleted = true  WHERE OrderID = " + OrderID;
```

Can anyone help, I have been researching this for awhile now.

Comment: I would expect to set to `1`, not to `true`.

Comment: Oh, and be aware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What problem do you have or what exception raised?

Comment: @Uwe Kein, I am using this to prevent sql injection: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OrderID", OrderID);

and Shoaib, there are not exception raised, it was just not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is a reserved word in sql. Used with the order by clause to sort rows.

Encapsulate your table and column names with `[]` if they are keywords.

Try this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Order] SET OrderCompleted = 1 WHERE OrderID = " + OrderID + "";
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now... Thank you very much. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Its ok, happens sometimes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this: -

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Order] SET OrderCompleted = 1 WHERE OrderID = " + OrderID;
```

In SQL there is no data type for boolean but there is a data type `bit` which accepts zero (0) or one (1) but not true or false. As you are using a checkbox so you need to convert boolean value into integer before passing into the query.

Secondly, as mentioned by @nunespascal braces [] around Order word because Order is an SQL keyword.

Comment: and also using the "1" instead of "true".